# The multi-part identifier “System.Data.DataRowView” could not be bound." SQL SERVER + VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, sqlcommand

Hi I am making a small database using sql server as the back and vb as the front end, I have nearly made it work however I have stumbled across this error.

My code is provided below would really appreciate some help.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        conn = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select tarif from tarif_sewa where kode_tarif = " & ComboBox1.Text & "", conn)
        TextBox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        conn.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What is the content of ComboBox.Text?

Comment: the content is kode_tarif like "1,2,3" as integer

Comment: Are you sure that you get this error from this code? It seems that this error could be raised if you use the SelectedItem property, not if you use the Text property of the combobox. Well, cannot post code in comments, so I suggest a possible workaround below as an answer. You tell me if it works

Comment: if i use combobox1.selecteditem, then the error msg is "Operator '&' is not defined for string "select tarif from tarif_sewa whe" and type 'DataRowView'."

Comment: That's expected because a SelectedItem is probably a DataRowView and cannot be concatenated with a string using the operator &. But with the property Text this error should not happen. Have you tried my answer below?

Comment: i see, i've tried your answer below, but the error msg is "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int." on TextBox2.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar

Comment: What kind of datatype is the field `tarif` on the table? Need to apply a conversion on that line

Comment: tarif datatype is int

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it still didn't work. the err msg is `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.`

Comment: Could you show how the combobox is initially filled?

Comment: here is my code for combobox.1
`conn = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
        Dim kodeTarif As New SqlDataAdapter("select kode_tarif from tarif_sewa", conn)
        Dim dtTarif As DataTable
        dtTarif = New DataTable()
        kodeTarif.Fill(dtTarif)
        ComboBox1.DataSource = (dtTarif)
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "kode_tarif"`

Comment: Sorry, but I have no more idea. If you are willing to share your project on a file sharing site like SkyDrive, Google Drive etc. I am willing to look at your whole project.

Answer (score 0):

The correct approach at your query should be

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Using conn = New SqlConnection(connectionstring)
    Using cmd = New SqlCommand("select tarif from tarif_sewa where kode_tarif = @p1", conn)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", ComboBox1.Text)
        Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            ' A better conversion could be applied knowing the exact datatype of tarif '
            TextBox2.Text = result.ToString
        End If
    End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

This will replace your string concatenation with a parameterized query and enclose your disposable object in a Using statement.

However I can't figure out how this error could be emitted by your code that (while it is not to be recommended as best practice) is not formally wrong